# Generate two-dimensional normal distribution given a mean and standard deviation

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for a two-dimensional analog to the `numpy.random.normal` routine, i.e. `numpy.random.normal` generates a one-dimensional array with a mean, standard deviation and sample number as input, and what I'm looking for is a way to generate points in two-dimensional space with those same input parameters.

Looks like `numpy.random.multivariate_normal` can do this, but I don't quite understand what the `cov` parameter is supposed to be. The following excerpt describes this parameter in more detail and is from the scipy docs:

> Covariance matrix of the distribution. Must be symmetric and
>   positive-semidefinite for “physically meaningful” results.

Later in the page, in the examples section, a sample `cov` value is given:

```
cov = [[1,0],[0,100]] # diagonal covariance, points lie on x or y-axis
```

The concept is still quite opaque to me, however.

If someone could clarify what the `cov` should be or suggest another way to generate points in two-dimensional space given a mean and standard deviation using python I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you pass `size=[1, 2]` to the `normal()` function, you get a 2D-array, which is actually what you're looking for:

```
>>> numpy.random.normal(size=[1, 2])
array([[-1.4734477 , -1.50257962]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would I use that to generate a distribution with, say, 500 points? Looks like that only gives me one x, y pair

Comment: You adjust the size to be `[500, 2]`. However, it depends on your dataset… Maybe it's better to go with `[1, 1000]` or even looping through and generate each one separately, or whatever ; )

Answer (score 2):

normal generated random points,

```
np.random.normal(10, 5, size=[100, 2])
```

10 is the mean value, 5 is the standart deviation.

Answer (score -3):

For random samples from N(mu, sigma^2), use:

sigma * np.random.randn(...) + mu

Examples

> np.random.randn()
> 2.1923875335537315 #random

Two-by-four array of samples from N(3, 6.25):

> 2.5 * np.random.randn(2, 4) + 3

array(
[[-4.49401501,  4.00950034, -1.81814867,  7.29718677],
[ 0.39924804,  4.68456316,  4.99394529,  4.84057254]])

```
https://numpy.org/doc/1.15/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html
```

Comment: Answer is unclear
As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34756889)